# UIButton Multiple Labels Using UIControlStates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I know with a UIButton, I can add additional UILabels as subviews:

```
[myButton addSubview: myLabel];
```

And (at least, with the default title label) I can set its text color when tapped by using:

```
[myButton setTitleColor:someColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

My question is, how can I implement this functionality for additional UILabels added to the UIButton (if this is possible)?

Comment: What's the reason for adding multiple labels to a button?

Comment: So that they can have different font properties.

Comment: You're correct that it's better to change the existing title's property, than to add more subViews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass UIButton and add your additional labels in there as instance variables. Then override `-setHighlighted` and `-setSelected` to adjust the additional labels as desired. 
FYI - you call `[myButton setTitleColor...]`, not `[myButton.titleLabel setTitleColor...]`

Comment: That actually makes a lot more sense than my approach. Thanks.

Comment: If you simply want to change the title color, you don't need to add more labels.  Just change the existing label's color.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @PetahChristian that wasn't my question. I do want multiple labels because I want them to be formatted differently from one another.

Comment: You want one button to show multiple labels for a single control state?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set `myLabel`s text color, before you added it as a subView.

Otherwise, you'll have to enumerate through the button's subviews and change each of your added label's text colors.

**Update:**

You can change the button title's font as follows:

```
myButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "...", 10)
```

You can change the button's title color as follows:

```
colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.brownColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Comment: I have the subviews added. I'd like to change each of their font colors for the control event UIControlStateHighlighted, but I realized adding an action for the button is probably a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

It seems my way of going about it isn't easy, but I realized I can just add an action to the `UIButton` for the event `UITouchDown`, and change the labels accordingly in the action.